# Call NodeJs function at a specific moment in time

Tags: javascript, node.js, task

Is there a way to **automate functions** and call them at a specific mooment in time with **Node.Js** ? More precisely, I would like to create a reminder with node js. When I receive the date from the user, I have to send notification to remind him/her of something.

I know setTimeout() function but is it really good idea when I have large database of users ?

Thank you.

Comment: i would turn the notification routine into a microservice, and have a cron job execute the service, which looks for notifications to send out when it runs, clearing them out once sent. that way, you won't lose setTimeouts if the server restarts.

Comment: Good idea, thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` and keep all the work inside your server, but for a large number of users, you would not necessarily want to set a timeout for every single user.  All you really need is a single timeout for the next user that needs to be notified.  When that timer fires, you then set a timer for the next user that needs to be notified and so on.

This can be done with an array of objects that you sort by the notification time.  Each time you add something to the array, you cancel your current timer, add the new notification to the array, sort the array and set a timer for the earliest notification.

When a timer fires, you remove that item from the array and schedule the next one.

And, since you likely want this to survive a server restart, you save the notification array (probably in JSON format) to a file or to a database each time you modify it so you can reload that data upon a server restart.

FYI, there are scheduling modules for node.js that already offer this type of functionality if you'd prefer to pick up code someone else has already written.

Examples of some of these modules:

[node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

[agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda)

[node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a Scheduler or a cron job (its origin is from Linux OS).

In NodeJS you can find the [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) that implement the same idea.